# Tripple backslash in Bash 'echo -e' is acting strange

Tags: bash, escaping, echo, ansi-escape

I have multiple Bash variables for ANSI terminal colors. One is `ANSI_NOCOLOR` and defined as this:

```
ANSI_NOCOLOR="\e[0m"
```

When I use it togather with a backslash character `\` (escaped as `\\` in Bash strings), I get an unexpected output.

Example:

```
echo -e "command --with --many --options \\$ANSI_NOCOLOR"
echo -e "--more --options"
```

This results in:

```
command --with --many --options \e[0m
--more --options
```

**This example can be reduced to:**

```
$ echo -e "\\\e[0m"
\e[0m
```

Why is a tripple backslash in Bash not acting as normally known from other C-like languages?

**Expected / C-like behavior:**

Escape sequences are left-associative. Thus,

1. the first two `\\` are printed as `\`,
2. the remaining `\` is doing a look-ahead(1) to find `e` for creating the `ESC` character.

---

**Workaround:**
After some planing with backslashes, I found, that 5 !! backslashes are required. I still would like to read an explanation, why it behaves as it is.

```
$ echo -e "\\\\\e[33mfoo\e[0m"
\foo
```

*It's hard to control a color-reset sequence, so my workaround uses two ANSI color escape sequences, to set it to yellow and back to default.*

Comment: It doesn't make sense to expect what you expect. Maybe read up on the difference between single and double quotes; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: Also; don't use `echo -e` anyway, as it's a portability nightmare. Probably look at `printf` instead.

Comment: Single quotes do not expand variables, thus double quotes are required. `printf` has the same behavior regarding triple backslashes.

Comment: Neither `echo` nor `printf` has this behavior wrt triple backslashes. It's an invocation problem. If you do `echo -e "\\\e"` then you are invoking echo with *two* backslashes, not three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because there are two levels of escaping at work:

1. escaping for the double quoted string. This pass recognizes `\\` but not `\e`
2. `echo -e` escape sequences. This pass recognizes both `\\` and `\e`.

So:

1. The initial string is `\\\e`
2. The double quotes replace the `\\` but leaves the unsupported `\e` alone
3. You now have `\\e`
4. Echo replaces the `\\`
5. You now have `\e`

This is one of the many reasons why you should prefer `printf` over `echo` whenever any value may contain a backslash.

Comment: `printf` gives you fine grained control over which sequences will or won't be expanded. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with your code, but an unrelated example would be `var='\x40'; printf "%s becomes $var\n" "$var"` which prints `\x40 becomes @`, showing the escape sequences in the value both expanded and unexpanded.

Comment: The example is shown in listing 1 and 2 of my question. Several color escape sequences are defined and are used in `echo` statements. When writing a \ at the end of a line short before the resetting color sequence, I get 3 backslashes. The \ is used to designate a line continuation.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Yes, that's a quoting issue. The parameter you give echo should be `...\\\e...` but due to your quoting you instead give it `...\\e...`, and `echo` understandably does not do what you intended